# How do I get only one object that matches search criteria from array of objects in a document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of **topics** with  data structure like this :

```
{
  topicId:"LSCv0mnb" ,
  posts:[
   {
    postId: "nNP8UDxL",
    createdBy: "Sam"
   }, 
   {
    postId: "aJ8UxLa",
    createdBy: "Bob"
   }
 ]
}

{
  topicId:"hlsTOgAX" ,
  posts:[
   {
    postId: "E3cJa0Nm",
    createdBy: "Samanta"
   }, 
   {
    postId: "Rt0xQnAy",
    createdBy: "Jessica"
   }
 ]
}
```

In my case, I need to get just a specific post from the array of posts. So what I'm currently doing is I use `findOne` to  find specific topic:

```
const topic = await this.db.collection('topics').findOne({ topicId: { $eq: topicId })
```

And than I just loop through `topic.posts` to get a post by `postId`:

```
const post = topic.posts.find(post => post.postId === postId)
```

I have 2 questions.

Can I query MongoDB to get just a post from array of posts and nothing else? For example, I have
a `topicId` and a `postId` , and my expected return value would be:

```
{
  postId: "E3cJa0Nm",
  createdBy: "Samanta"
}
```

If it's possible to do using MongoDB, is it better to do it on my web-server from performance prospective ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregations

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$match` to match the elements
- `$replaceRoot` to make it root

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$posts"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "posts.postId": "E3cJa0Nm",
      "posts.createdBy": "Samanta"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$posts"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_OgwoKRk_BI)**

Comment: Thank you very much!  Could you answer my second question ?

Comment: Few aggregations are expensive when it comes to large number of data. U can perform in db side, but make sure your db also manage the loads. When you do in db side, the query might be faster than getting into server. Else you can get chunk of data and perform

Comment: Also, this query doesn't use `topicId`. So that means it will go through topics and check posts in each topic until it finds one. It seems to be an issue, no?

Comment: Yes, so what we can do is, first filter out the topic and do the mathc, this will be faster, it wont go through all documents. See https://mongoplayground.net/p/pzEa7C1ATxf